# localStorage sign up users how to redirect without losing data

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem with a sign up form. Every time a user creates an account I use localStorage to save the form values. But if after the submit button the user redirects to another page it saves only the last user data who signed up. If after sign up I dont redirect the user to another page I can have more than one users. What can I do to save more users (using localStorage)
the code is:

```
 var passwords=[];
  var people= [];
function submitSignUp(){ 
     var usr = signupform.elements["username"].value;
     var pass = signupform.elements["password"].value;
     people.push(usr);
     passwords.push(pass);   
     localStorage.setItem( 'peoplenames', JSON.stringify(people));
     localStorage.setItem('urpasswords',JSON.stringify(passwords)); 
     window.location.href="accountCreated.html";            
}
```

also I use a input type button and not submit because I have the same problem with the submit input. What can I do? Thanks.

Comment: Where do `people` and `passwords` come from in your code? Are these filled with all the previous values already? (And what sense does a sign-up that is processed only client-side make anyway …?)

Comment: Its for simulation only thats why I want localStorage also I edit the code with the arrays

Comment: Now you have shown us how those arrays are initialized empty. But where’s the part where you read the previously stored values back, before storing new ones?

Comment: so before I push the new values I have to re-save the values that I saved previously?

Comment: No, but you have to _read_ them back from storage, so that your arrays are filled with the previous values already before you push a new one into them – otherwise you just push one element into an empty array, and when you store that, all previous values are lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/neoaptt/35opjyju/)

So here is the jsfiddle that should work for you.

some key things are the following.

```
if(localStorage.getItem('users') != null){
    users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('users'));
}
```

this code checks if the users string has been set for the current page. If users has not been set on local storage is skips this step entirely.

as for processing information from page to page, you will need to do 1 of 3 things.

1. Send all your calls via ajax. [JQuery Get](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) would allow you to stay on the current page while loading content from other pages. You would use the `get` or `post` like an [IFrame](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp)
2. Navigate through your site using only `get` methods. Javascript wasn't meant for this, and this doesn't give you much control over the initial state of a webpage.
3. If you don't want to use Javascript for the rest of your life, or have personal information that shouldn't be held on a local machine. IE: passwords. Use a [Server Scripting Language](http://www.w3schools.com/php/).

In the end it is up to you to decide what to do, but my recommendation would be to use **Server Scripting Language** and some sort of [**Database**](http://www.mysql.com/). These are web standards and are marketable skills.